# Paired difference of columns in dataframe to generate dataframe with 1.3 million columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I have a dataframe with 1600 columns.

The dataframe `df` looks like where the column names are `1, 3 , 2`:

```
Row Labels  1   3   2
41730Type1  9   6   5
41730Type2  14  12  20
41731Type1  2   15  5
41731Type2  3   20  12
41732Type1  8   10  5
41732Type2  8   18  16
```

I need to create the following dataframe `df2` pythonically:

```
Row Labels  (1, 2)  (1, 3)  (2, 3)
41730Type1  -4      -3       1
41730Type2  6       -2       -8
41731Type1  3       13       10
41731Type2  9       17        8
41732Type1  -3      2         5
41732Type2  8       10        2
```

where e.g. `column (1, 2)` is created by `df[2] - df[1]`

The column names for `df2` are created by pairing the column headers of `df1` such that second element of each name is greater than first e.g. `(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)`

The second challenge is can pandas dataframe support 1.3 million columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `combinations` for the column , then create the `dict` and `concat` it back

```
import itertools
l=itertools.combinations(df.columns,2)
d={'{0[0]}|{0[1]}'.format(x) : df[x[0]]-df[x[1]] for x in [*l]  }
newdf=pd.concat(d,axis=1)
            1|3  1|2  3|2
RowLabels                
41730Type1    3    4    1
41730Type2    2   -6   -8
41731Type1  -13   -3   10
41731Type2  -17   -9    8
41732Type1   -2    3    5
41732Type2  -10   -8    2
```

Answer (score 1):

[itertools combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) seems the obvious choice, same as @YOBEN_S, a different route to the solution, using numpy arrays and dictionary

```
from itertools import combinations
new_data = combinations(df.to_numpy().T,2)
new_cols = combinations(df.columns, 2)

result = {key : np.subtract(arr1,arr2)
          if key[0] > key[1]
          else np.subtract(arr2,arr1)
          for (arr1, arr2), key
          in zip(new_data,new_cols)}

outcome = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result,orient='index').sort_index().T

outcome


    (1, 2)  (1, 3)  (3, 2)
0   -4       -3       1
1    6       -2      -8
2    3       13      10
3    9       17       8
4   -3       2        5
5    8      10        2
```